# How to set a timer for a string to trigger periodically?

Tags: swift, time, timer, swiftui, periodicity

I'm making a FlashCards app and I would like to set a timer for the cards in a way so that if the user knows the answer, the card will trigger again next day, then if he knows it again, it will trigger in 5 days and so on.
I haven't found anything related to this, any help with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get track of the Dates and the User's performance with each card. (You can use a Timer here. For instance, if the User 'knows' the answer within a minute, the card will be marked as 'correct' (known), and beyond that time, the card will be marked as 'wrong' (not yet mastered and needs to be repeated).
Create a logic wherein the cards marked as 'wrong' will popup after a few days or so.
I suggest you use CoreData to save the `Dates` when the User uses the Flashcard app. 
Also, you will need to learn how to use `DateComponents()`.
Here's a great [resource](https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/add-days-months-years-to-current-date-in-swift/#:%7E:text=To%20add%20more%20days%20to,the%20DateComponents()%20Swift%20structs.&text=print(futureDate!),%3D%201%20let%20futureDate%20%3D%20Calendar.).

Comment: I came up with a solution that should work using the CoreData for dates and the DateComponents() to establish future dates. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In case when users don't quit app you can use [Timer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer). However, this is only expected for short intervals.

```
let minute = 60
let anotherTimeInterval = 2 * minute

var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: minute, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

@objc func updateTimer() {

    // do something

    timer.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: anotherTimeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

Normally, you need to prepare a specific data source for a specific day. For example, in your case, you can add a flag or date to each card and use that flag or date to add that card to the data source on a specific date.

Comment: i'm sorry but i think this function is not useful. We do not use an app for more than 5 days in a row. The Timer will be stopped every time the User quits the app.

Comment: Ok. In this case you need to prepare a specific data source for a specific day. For example, in your case, you can add a flag or date to each card and use that flag or date to add that card to the data source on a specific date. I have updated my answer.